# Scala infix / postfix operators

Tags: scala, postfix-operator

I want to make the following code work, but I get an compile error: '
object A#c does not take parameters'

"b" c d

If I leave off 'd' the code compiles just fine. It must have something to do with infix/postfix operators which are new for me. Could somebody please help me make the above code work, and also explain to me (or give me some pointers) why the above code syntax is not working?

My class definitions:

```
object A {
    implicit def stringToA(b: String) : A = new A(b)
}

class A(private val b: String) {

    object c {
        println("c")

        def d: Unit = {
            println("d!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in scala `a op b` is `a.op(b)`, so your `"b" c d` will be `"b".c(d)`, but what you want is `"b".c.d`, so you will need to write it fully.

If you really need to write it `"b" c d`, you could try to make `d` an arg of a method `c`, for instance

```
trait D {}

object d extends D

class A {

   def c(ignored: D) = println("d!")

}
```

or possibly

```
class A {

   object c {
      def apply(ignored: D) = println("d!")
   }
}
```

Comment: Didier thanks for your answer. I got it working. The only drawback in my opinion is that there are a lot of objects involved. For small projects I think it is not a problem, but for bigger projects I'm afraid that you are losing the overview of which classes belong to each other. However I think scala is a cool language

Comment: That sure is not something I would do nor encourage. Use it only when doing a DSL and you really need it to be `"b" c d`.